# Complete clueless how does Facebook OAuth (FBOAuth) work

Tags: 7, social-network

I follow this video to get my Facebook App Id and secret :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyDXlSUHaE8

Drupal module: https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth

In the setting I added Facebook App Id and secret

In block: I add in my content page.

When I click on Facebook logo and I manage to register.

As a result, I receive this error. 
[image]
After that this error message appear as well.
The account with username example and email example@gmail.com is not yet activated.

I not sure do I need to continues change setting in Facebook App or I need to do any setting in drupal. Need help.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried activating the account?

Comment: @Clive I have updated my question. I not sure what does it mean activating my account....how to activate?

Comment: On your FB management page (developers.facebook.com / Status & Review) there's a switch where you make the app live to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message comes from the FBOauth module:

```
function fboauth_login_user($account) {
  global $user;

  if ($account->status) {
    $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
    user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
  }
  else {
    if ($account->access) {
      drupal_set_message(t('The account with username %name and email %mail ' . 
        'is blocked.',
        array('%name' => $account->name,
        '%mail' => $account->mail,)), 'error');
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message(t('The account with username %name and email %mail ' . 
        'is not yet activated.',
        array('%name' => $account->name,
        '%mail' => $account->mail,)), 'error');

    }
  }

  return !empty($user->uid);
}
```

So the user you're trying to log in with has not yet been activated *within Drupal*. Once the administrator has activated the account, the user will be able to log in using Facebook.

This is the correct behaviour; un-approved accounts should not be accessible just because they've been signed up through Facebook.